# Doubt regarding invariance of discrete absolute value under automorphism

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, p-adic-analysis

I have been reviewing some basic algebraic number theory and $p$-adic analysis, and the following thought crossed my mind: if $F/ \mathbb Q$ be a finite Galois extension, and $\eta$ be a $\mathbb Q$-automorphism of $F$, then it is easy to show that $\eta$ leaves the ring of integers of $F$ invariant, that is,  $\eta\mathcal{O}_F = \mathcal{O}_F$. I was wondering what happens about $p$-integers: more precisely, if $v$ be a non-archimdedean (hence discrete) place of $F$ and $p$ be the unique rational prime satisfying $|p|_v<1$, with $| \cdot |_v$ normalized such that $|p|_v = 1/p$, can it be said that for any $\alpha \in \mathcal{O}_{v, F} := \{x \in F: |x|_v \leq 1\}$, $|\alpha|_v=|\eta\alpha|_v$?

It seems that this question only reduces to checking whether $\eta\mathcal{O}_{v, F} \subset \mathcal{O}_{v, F}$ for any $\mathbb Q$-automorphism $\eta$ of $F$: for if this were true and $p^r:=|\alpha|_v$ with $r \in \mathbb Z_{\leq 0}$, then $p^r\alpha \in \mathcal{O}_{v, F}$ and $p^{r-1} \alpha \not\in \mathcal{O}_{v, F}$, whence $p^r\eta\alpha = \eta(p^r\alpha) \in \mathcal{O}_{v, F}$, $p^{r-1}\eta\alpha = \eta(p^{r-1}\alpha) \not\in \mathcal{O}_{v, F}$, so that indeed $|\eta\alpha|_v = p^r$. Is my reasoning for this reduction correct?

On the other hand, it is not clear to me why $\eta\mathcal{O}_{v, F} \subset \mathcal{O}_{v, F}$ - if we show this, the above argument will imply that any automorphism of $F$ is also an isometry with respect to non-archimedean valuations of $F$. However, I can see an intuitive reason for this happening: namely, the invariance (i.e. constancy) of ramification indices of all primes of the finite Galois extension $F$ lying over a fixed prime of $\mathbb Q$. I would really appreciate if someone could give me any hint as to how to complete the argument, if the assertion under consideration is true, - and a counterexample otherwise. In the former case, is my intuition of invariance of ramification indices correct (in the other case, why is it flawed)?

Comment: Pretty sure that the claim is false. Let $F = \mathbb Q \left[i\right]$ and $\xi = 2+i$ and $\tau = 2-i$. Then, $1/\tau$ is an "integer" for the $\xi$-valuation, but $\overline{1/\tau} = 1/\xi$ is not.

Comment: On the other hand, $\left\{x \in F \mid p^k x \text{ is an algebraic integer for some } k \geq 0 \right\}$ is a subring of $F$ and (pretty obviously) invariant under any $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra automorphisms of $F$.

Comment: I see, thank you. Could you please tell me where the ramification-index-intuition fails? Thanks. Also changed notation.

Comment: Afraid I can't, as I don't have that intuition myself. But I think the underlying ur-problem is that while only one $p$ corresponds to a given $v$, there are usually many $v$s corresponding to a given $p$.

Comment: As noted in other comments, this is false for a number field $F/\mathbb Q$. However, it is true if you work in the completion, i.e., a finite Galois extension $F/\mathbb Q_p$. There is then a unique extension of the absolute value to $F$, so $\operatorname{Gal}(F/\mathbb Q_p)$ preserves the absolute value. Actually, for Galois extensions of number fields, Galois acts transitively on the primes lying over $p$, and each prime lying over $p$ determines a unique $p$-adic absolute value on $F$.